# Create a new Uri from an Absolute Uri AS IT IS?

Tags: c#, uri, spaces

I would like to create a new Uri after replacing some characters from the original Uri. 
I am calling

```
string original = uri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("foo", "bar").Replace("xyz", "abc");
```

Now, after replacing instances, when I try to create a new Uri from the string

```
Uri newUri = new Uri(original);
```

The Uri always returns as a `ToString()` representation of the Uri, i.e it is human-readable i.e  - The Uri retains `Spaces` instead of `%20` which is **NOT** what I would like to have.

**To make it more clear:**

Original string = [http://foo.example.com/images/Cute%20Cats/New%20Images/cat-1.jpg](http://samsuria.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cute-cat-wallpapers.jpg)

New Uri = [http://foo.example.com/images/Cute Cats/New Images/cat-1.jpg](http://samsuria.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cute-cat-wallpapers.jpg)

Expected = [http://foo.example.com/images/Cute%20Cats/New%20Images/cat-1.jpg](http://samsuria.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cute-cat-wallpapers.jpg)

So, finally how can I create a new Uri from the above Original String which is AS IT IS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [OriginalString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to display the escaped uri.

```
Console.WriteLine(newUri.OriginalString);
```

The escaped version your seeing does exist in your `Uri` object but the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method called on it will display the unescaped version.

Comment: I'm not calling the `ToString()` please read the question carefully!

Comment: How are you seeing the value to confirm that the URI was not created properly? Your question doesn't actually provide information on where you're seeing the new incorrect URI so I took a guess and assumed you're printing it somewhere which called the `ToString` method (e.g. `Console.WriteLine` method).